# ajax data response always 0 in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to load some data from mysql to a div via ajax php. The id field which is auto increment is always equal to zero.

I have tried using get, post etc but none is working

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var uid = $(this).data("customer_id");   // it will get id of clicked row

    $('#txtHint').html(''); // leave it blank before ajax call
    $('#mySidenav').show();      // load ajax loader

    $.ajax({
      url: 'getCustomerDetails.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'customer_id='+uid,
      dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function(data){
      console.log(data);  
      $('#txtHint').html('');    
      $('#txtHint').html(data); // load response 
      $('#modal-loader').hide();      // hide ajax loader 
    })
    .fail(function(){
      $('#txtHint').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Something went wrong, Please try again...');
      $('#modal-loader').hide();
    });

  });

 });

</script>


        <?php

include_once('../../config/dbconfig.php');


    if (isset($_REQUEST['customer_id'])) {

        $id = intval($_REQUEST['customer_id']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id=:id";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
        $row=$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="col-md-4" >
                <?php echo $row['first_name'];?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <?php echo $id;?><br/>


<?php
}

?>
```

The result is not echo the firs_name because the $id is always 0.
I want to get the individual $id(auto_increment)
when is done it should display user record

Comment: fyi: you've only set the `fetchMode` and executed the query, no fetching is actually happening

Comment: Use `$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();` instead of `$row=$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: fetch_assoc() is giving error Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc() -  @Dejvid

Answer (score 1):

Start with debugging your actual result from the database.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['customer_id'])) {

        $id = intval($_REQUEST['customer_id']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id=:id";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
        $row=$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You are NOT checking for errors.

Two suggestions:

1) You are using `<?php echo $row['first_name'];?>`. If you inspected the resultset you could see what is wrong with that. Just output the result in the (wrongly named) $row variable with print_r() and the like. I am sure you will see what went wrong.

2) I strong advise AGAINST using $_REQUEST. It is lazy and errorprone. Do you know where the 'customer_id' came from? Session? Cookie? POST? Or Get? If you are passing information via GET => use GET

Comment: Agree with everything, just a clarification. Why is `$row` variable name wrong? Is it because it is too vague? (I'm not OP)

Comment: @Dejvid I said that because he isn't fetching a row, only setting the fetchmode. Your comment clearly told him. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `customer_id` is a unique key in your database and only one row is returned for each id in your database. So, how to correctly use PDO statements:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id=:id";
//Prepare your SELECT statement.
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
//The Primary Key of the row that we want to select.
$id = intval($_REQUEST['customer_id']);
//I highly recomment not to use $_REQUEST, use $_GET or even better $_POST

//Bind our value to the paramater :id.
$statement->bindValue(':id', $id);

//Execute our SELECT statement.
$statement->execute();

//Fetch the row.
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//If $row is FALSE, then no row was returned.
if($row === false){
    echo $id . ' not found!';
} else{
    echo 'Found: ' . $row['first_name'];
}
```

**EDIT**
Also, change your ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getCustomerDetails.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {customer_id:uid}
})
```